# how can I set writer rules for all elements in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

how could I set this global for all elements:

```
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev){
        var el = [ "p", "div", "table", "tbody", "tr", "td", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "ul", "center" ];
        el.forEach(function(v) {
            ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules(v,
                {
                    indent: false,
                    breakBeforeOpen: true,
                    breakAfterOpen: false,
                    breakBeforeClose: false,
                    breakAfterClose: false
                }
            );
        });
    });
```

it is boring to make this as array of elements? does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

There's no API which would let you configure it for all elements. But still you can combine [`CKEDITOR.dtd`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd) with [`CKEDITOR.tools.extend`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.tools-method-extend) like:

```
var dtd = CKEDITOR.dtd;

for ( var e in CKEDITOR.tools.extend( {}, 
    dtd.$block, 
    dtd.$listItem, 
    dtd.$tableContent ) 
) {
    this.setRules( e, { ... } );
}
```