# fillEmptyBlocks config in CKEditor 4.6.2 does not help manipulate insertion of <br> tags in empty DIVs

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

***Problem 1:*** I consume the following plugins as part of a customized build of the basic version of CKEditor 4.6.2 - basicstyles, dialogui, dialog, clipboard, button, toolbar, enterkey, floatingspace, undo, divarea. The empty DIV container blocks have `<br>` elements added by CKEditor which I am trying to prevent.

The config file looks like this -

```js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {

  config.title = false;

  config.allowedContent = true;

  config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;

  // Toolbar groups configuration.
  config.toolbar = ... 
};
```

`fillEmptyBlocks = false;` did not prevent CKEditor 4.6.2 from inserting the `<br>` elements. I tried doing what https://stackoverflow.com/a/34849579 suggests by having all the line-break rules set to FALSE and I could not get around the problem.

I tried it with the whole basic version of CKEditor 4.6.2 and the released version of 4.5.11 and this still occurs in them. However, this problem does not exist in CKEditor 4.1.3 and 4.4.0. Am I missing something as part of a config or should I have any additional plugin to not have this issue with 4.6.2?

***Problem 2:*** 
Pressing backspace in an empty div block removes the div block from the DOM. This again happens with 4.6.2 and 4.5.11 and not on 4.1.3 or 4.4.0, is there a config that I could be missing?

**Edited:** `<br>` tags are being inserted despite having fillEmptyBlocks set to false in all the versions post CKEditor 4.4.7, it does not happen with 4.4.6. Looking at the release notes, http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12735 is the change that has gone into 4.4.7 Is there another way to fix this then?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed similar kind of WYSIWYG editor using CKEDITOR 4 where everything is working fine although I used `ckeditor.replace`

However, I uploaded it in the github. So, you can refer there and compare and fix your code if you want.

[Click here for the github project.](https://github.com/Rakin061/WebDocument-Editor)

Please ask me if you face any problems!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code it is working for me:

For removing br on load

```
$('your_id').ckeditor();    
        CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() { 
            $('div.application').find('br').remove();   // remove br tag added on empty divs
        });
```

for removing &nbsp use this in destroy function:

```
for(CKname in CKEDITOR.instances) // delete multiple instances of ckeditor
        {
            CKEDITOR.instances[CKname].destroy(function(){
                $("your_id").html(function (i, html) {
                    return html.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ''); // remove &nbsp;
                });
            })
        }
```